# Polynomial Taken Modulo 27

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Prove that there exists an integer polynomial $P(X)$ such that $P(n)+4^n \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$.

for all $n \geq 0$

I think that since $\text{ord}_{27}(4)=9$, we only need to take the cases from P(1), P(2), ..., P(9)..

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that $9$ is enough.  [Fit a polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) $P$ to the points $(n, -4^n)$ for $n \in \{0 \dots 26\}$.  Using the fact that $\text{ord}_{27}(4) \vert 27$, since $P(x) \equiv P(x+27) \pmod{27}$, by induction the property holds for all $x$.

Note that the generalized equation $P(n) + b^n \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$ is solvable no matter what the order of the base, just fit a number of points equal to the least common multiple of the modulus and the order.

Comment: I need an integer polynomial; i.e. polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: Do you know how to make the constructed polynomial satisfy the integer polynomial condition? I am thinking of reducing stuff mod 9 (-4^n is always congruent to 2 mod 3 )

Comment: You're absolutely right, I forgot about this condition.  It turns out that if you fit 9 points http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit+polynomial+4%5E0%2C+4%5E1%2C+4%5E2%2C+4%5E3%2C+4%5E4%2C+4%5E5%2C+4%5E6%2C+4%5E7%2C+4%5E8 you can multiply it by $58240 = 4480 \cdot 13$ to get an integer polynomial that is the same mod $27$.  This should be possible as long as none of the denominators of the coefficients in the fit are divisible by $3$.  But I don't yet know how to prove that none of them are without actually performing the fit.